# Are inline expressions compiled on run time or build time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In ASP.NET web pages we use special tags like `<%# %>,<%= %>,<%@ %>`and`<%$ %>`.

I'm just curious if those tags are compiled or not? Do we have to build the project to make it work, or is it compiled at run time?

Comment: If your talking about web forms then, yes i's compiled, but only either when the page is first accessed or by the asp.net pre-compiler, if you run it. It isn't compiled when you build in visual studio. This applies to the whole aspx/markup page not just any `<% ... %>` blocks.

Comment: makes sense...so even the server control work in the same way right?

Comment: Server controls (classes that inherit from system.web.ui.control) are slightly different, they are compiled when you build. User controls (classes that inherit from System.Web.UI.UserControl and have an .ascx markup file) are the same though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually that code is compiled at runtime when the page is first hit. Depending on your settings in your web.config file it compiles in Debug or Release mode.

It is possible though to pre-compile that code before you deploy your project. See [How to: Precompile ASP.NET Web Sites for Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It uses the `aspnet_compiler` to compile the ASP.NET code to an assembly.

Comment: Although the code is JIT:ed, that's not the difference as all code is JIT:ed. The code in the page is also compiled first.

Answer (score 1):

They are recompiled first time page code is executed after web application starts or the page is changed.

Answer (score 1):

It is compiled when it is loaded into IIS, and if you have selected the precompile option when you build the website, they have been precompiled, just like with a DLL.